# Angular multiple ng-options parent / child

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-options

I have a number of `select` input children thats data changes depending on the parents selection.

Please see this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Taylorsuk/pen/bdrPmO?editors=101) for the type of data that will form my parent child relationship.

My starting piece of code is here:

Controller

```
$scope.params = ['Sets', 'Reps', 'Colour', 'Time', 'Weight'];

$scope.children = [{
    'Sets': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
  }, {
    'Reps': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
  }, {
    'Colour': ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Pink']
  },

];
```

HTML

```
<label class="item item-input item-select">
    <div class="input-label positive">
        Param
    </div>
    <select ng-model="param">
        <option ng-repeat="param in params" value="{{param}}">{{param}}</option>
    </select>
</label>
<label ng-show="param" class="item item-input item-select">
    <div class="input-label positive">
        Sets
    </div>
    <select ng-model="param">
        <option ng-repeat="param in params" value="{{param}}">{{param}}</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

The children will only be visible if the corresponding parent is selected.

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the model like this:

```
$scope.params = ['Sets', 'Reps', 'Colour', 'Time', 'Weight'];

$scope.children = {
  'Sets': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
  'Reps': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
  'Colour': ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Pink']
};
```

And then do something like this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPZzdM

Comment: If you don't want to allow params with no children I would in this case pick out the params based on the children. lodash example:

    $scope.params = _.keys(children);

Comment: I am looking to getting the data from the `$scope` on submission is this possible by just passing `function(param)` that is what would be ideal. So then I would expect to see `param.Sets` etc...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I see a question here ;) But looking at your code the odd thing is that you set the same model in two different `select`s.

Try and change the `ng-model` in the second one to something distinct, e.g. `childParam`:

```
  <script id="popup-template.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <label class="item item-input item-select">
      <div class="input-label positive">
        Param
      </div>
      <select ng-model="param">
        <option ng-repeat="param in params" value="{{param}}">{{param}}</option>
      </select>
    </label>
    <label ng-show="param" class="item item-input item-select">
      <div class="input-label positive">
        Sets
      </div>
      <select ng-model="childParam">
        <option ng-repeat="param in params" value="{{param}}">{{param}}</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </script>
```